Create a Clonezilla blind install disc but do not change my PCRs
I am trying to create a blind installation bootable iso that re-installs my clonezilla image without prompts so I have the following line in my grub.cfg for my boot disk which was created from the clonezilla boot disc.
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live config noswap nolocales edd=on nomodeset noprompt ocs_prerun="mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt" ocs_prerun1="mount --bind /mnt/image_files /home/partimag/" ocs_live_run="ocs-sr -e -irhr -ius -iui -icds -iefi -j1 -j2 -p poweroff restoredisk XXX_IMAGE_NAME_XXX ada" ocs_live_extra_param="" keyboard-layouts=NONE ocs_live_batch="no" locales=en_US.UTF-8 vga=788 ip= nosplash
the flags I'm interested in are ocs-sr -e -irhr -ius -iui -icds -iefi -j1 -j2 -p poweroff which I think should stop the restore changing my boot sector from the original image, however it does seem to change my PCRs that I need to be stable for my TPM to lock to.
this is on a SELinux redhat 8u10 system
clonezilla is new to me and thanks in advance
